# Can we assign a number type to Dynamodb Hash key?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying a way to create a number type hash key in dynamodb table but it seems i can't find any way. Has anyone faced this issue and got any success with it? I am using Python to  insert values in dynamodb but it donot allows int type to be inserted in hash key and throws exception while it accepts the string type.

Comment: Add the exception and stack trace. There is no reason the `Number` data type should not work for a table definition. Are you trying to insert an integer as the hash key for a table whose key definition has the `String` datatype for its key?

Comment: Please also add the code where you generate the primary keys of the PutItem request and the table schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number-AttributeValue as a hash key of a table, if the table's schema has defined a number as the hash key. You define the schema of a table when you call the [CreateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-AttributeDefinitions) API for that table, using the AttributeDefinitions map.

Comment: I checked the reference but i still i cannot find what i am seaching for. Can you check if it provides to specify number as the type of hash key.